# AlertDialog setContentView not working API22

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a custom alert dialog, with a recyclerview in it, with a custom adapter. It works fine. This I discovered that on API22 the view doesn't show up. I just looks like this

[image]

The alert is empty. Just a white bar in the middle of the screen.

Here is the code:

```
 String itemSelected = foodList.get(position).getName();

    ArrayList<SearchItem> searchItemArrayList =  ListOfItemsClass.getArrayListAboutCategory(itemSelected, this);

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.more_info_dialog_layout);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();

    RecyclerView moreInfoReyclcerView = (RecyclerView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.more_info_recycler_view);
    moreInfoReyclcerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    moreInfoReyclcerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    MoreInfoAdapter moreInfoAdapter = new MoreInfoAdapter(searchItemArrayList);
    moreInfoReyclcerView.setAdapter(moreInfoAdapter);
```

Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/more_info_recycler_view"> . 
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the more_info_dialog_layout.xml?

Comment: done............

Comment: Is this the more_info_dialog_layout.xml? There is a recyclerview in it!

Comment: Yes, this is the more_info_dialog_layout.xml holding a recyclerview

Comment: You inflate this layout in a dialog? Meaning that is the dialog presenting a recyclerview?

Comment: Move `dialog.show();` at the end

Comment: Try changing the approach, inflate the layout first using the LayoutInflater approach, then find the recyclerview by doing inflatedView.findViewById... also use the AlertDialog.Builder class.

Comment: @mTak, moving dialog.show to the end didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Following Peterstev Uremgba, using AlertDialog.Builder class solved the problem:

```
 String itemSelected = notEatenThisWeekItemsYet.get(position).getName();

    ArrayList<SearchItem> searchItemArrayList =  ListOfItemsClass.getArrayListAboutCategory(itemSelected, this);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);

    LayoutInflater myLayout = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View dialogView = myLayout.inflate(R.layout.more_info_dialog_layout, null);

    alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);



    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);

    RecyclerView moreInfoReyclcerView = (RecyclerView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.more_info_recycler_view);
    moreInfoReyclcerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    moreInfoReyclcerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    MoreInfoAdapter moreInfoAdapter = new MoreInfoAdapter(searchItemArrayList);
    moreInfoReyclcerView.setAdapter(moreInfoAdapter);

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

    alertDialog.show();
```